# Why does my computer freeze when idle?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit

I'm having problems with my Windows Vista 64-bit machine.

It crashes or hangs a couple of times per day, usually when it's idle. When it crashes the screen freezes and and it takes no input from the mouse or the keyboard.

Where should I start looking to resolve this?

Comment: What anti-virus/firewall/etc. do you have?

Comment: +1 because I have the same problem, only it happens when I'm gaming.

Answer (score 1):

First step I'd take would be to check the device drivers, on the assumption that this didn't start happening suddenly, for example, after the installation of extra RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look in the event log in administrator tools and see if there is a particular event associated with the freezes.  Also it might be worth keeping an eye on the temperature inside your pc and checking out the memory with memcheck86.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rule out a faulty motherboard, or a faulty device. I once had an LG wireless PCI card, that would cause my system to randomly freeze up.... I only figured out it was the card after replacing RAM and Motherboard...

Answer (score 0):

I personally find that if it is just frozen - No bluescreen / random restart it is usually a faulty motherboard (can't rule it out, but a quick check is for blown capacitors) or a bad hard drive.

I am not saying that it isn't anything else as others have said, but I find that ram, drivers and devices, usually produce Blue screens and in my experience, 90+% of the time, if you mean that the machine is completely frozen, then it is one of the above.

Comment: Or a bad power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Reliability and Performance Monitor. It might give you a few clues into what is causing your computer to crash, especially if it's in any way software related.

[image]